# How to pause and resume the loop after the child thread completes

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java-threads

Can you help me, I have a problem using thread in java. I have two for loops, parent loop and child loop (for loop). In the child loop I use a thread object and use ExecutorService to manage. But I want to correspond each parent loop will wait for all thread and child loop to finish. Please help me!

I have done the following

**TestThread **

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Parent: " + i);
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                PrintTest p = new PrintTest(j);
                pool.execute(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PrintTest **

```
public class PrintTest implements Runnable {
    int id;
    public PrintTest(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Child: " + id);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result after compilation:
**Parent: 0**
**Parent: 1**
Child: 1
Child: 0
**Parent: 2**
Child: 2
Child: 4
Child: 3
**Parent: 3**
Child: 0
Child: 1
Child: 2
Child: 3
Child: 4
Child: 0
Child: 1
**Parent: 4**
Child: 2
Child: 3
Child: 4
Child: 0
Child: 1
Child: 2
Child: 3
Child: 0
Child: 4
Child: 2
Child: 1
Child: 3
Child: 4

Desired results:
**Parent: 0**
Child: x1
Child: x2
Child: x3
Child: x4
**Parent: 1**
Child: x1
Child: x2
Child: x3
Child: x4
**Parent: 2**
Child: x1
Child: x2
Child: x3
Child: x4
**Parent: 3**
Child: x1
Child: x2
Child: x3
Child: x4
**Parent: 4**
Child: x1
Child: x2
Child: x3
Child: x4

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use CountDownLatch in TestThread

Comment: Hi zuolun, my problem is solved, thank you for suport!